# Rails and Memcached Making Lots Of Requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I've recently added a memcache server that i'm planning to offload some stored stats into.

Everything is working, although when I started up the memcache daemon with verbose logging turned on, I could see that every request to my web server was also making a request to the memcache server, which would result in a cache miss.

This web server is getting hundreds of hits a minute which is resulting in hundreds of useless requests and misses to the memcache server.

The only cache stores/fetches i've made are in a single controller, at a specific time, so I can't understand why these requests are being made. It seems like a huge waste of resources to make that external request on every HTTP request.

Does anyone know what is going on? or how I can prevent this happening?

** UPDATE **
I turned config.action_controller.perform_caching off, and the excess requests stopped, but now I feel like iv disabled something I need in production.
Something doesn't feel right here.  Should EVERY request, including asset calls being calling out to memcache?

Comment: The memcached logging will show you what keys are being read/written to.  What are some of the keys?

Comment: The key matches the URL's being hit.  example, if I hit https://mysite.com/pages?type=4  I will see that URL as the key it's trying to retrieve.  None of them are being written though, only retrieved, which results in a miss.   Just hundreds and hundreds of GET calls, resulting in a key not found message.   
This is not normal behavior right?